# Array IndexOut of BoundException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
String[] date  = doc.select("div.bk-dett-date")
                    .select("[itemprop=datePosted]")
                    .text().split(" ");

String day = date[0];

String month = CrawlerUtilites.returnCorrectNumberOfMonth(date[1]);

String year = Integer.toString(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

The `String[] date` return a date in this format for example `"12 May"` or `"14 April"` and the exception is reported at `String month = ...(date[1])`.

How can I fix this exception? The final result have to be a date in format "YY MMM DD".

Comment: What is your day variable's value ? and also what's your date variable's value ?

Comment: The exception means that your `date` variable is of length 1, i.e. `date[1]` doesn't exist. That in turn means that what you extracted on line 1 doesn't have any space to be split on.

Comment: Clearly `date[1]` does not exist, as split ll always return an array of minimum 1 length, so `date[1]` is causing this error. I think `doc.select("div.bk-dett-date").select("[itemprop=datePosted]").text()` does not have any space.

Comment: Soumitri you are right but doc.select("div.bk-dett-date").select("[itemprop=datePosted]").text() return "18 May" with a space!

Comment: Instead of a verbatim space character, try splitting with `.split("\\s+")`, it will take any whitespace characters you have there (even new lines, etc) and split on that. Maybe there are two space chars or a carriage return or who knows.

Comment: @Val It doesn't works. Thanks

Comment: @DunceK10 Can you add a screenshot of the source code for that select from which you extract the data?

Comment: @Val <div class="bk-dett-date">Pubblicato il <span itemprop="datePosted">17 Maggio</span></div>

Comment: @DunceK10 Can you try to print out the `date` variable using `Arrays.toString(date)`?

Comment: @DunceK10 What did you do to make it work?

Comment: @Val I have printed the array with .toString and in a second moment i have taken the result from here with a substring. I know that It is a bad solution but it works so I don't care so much

Answer (score 0):

date[1] doesn't exist. Check your code, what you're getting in String[] date.

Answer (score -1):

In `split` method, if the regex is not found in the string, then also it ll return an array of length one, so there is no problem with `String day = date[0];` statement.

However, judging by the error you got, it's clear that `data[1]` does not exist, meaning the array is of length 1 which altogether means that your `doc.select("div.bk-dett-date").select("[itemprop=datePosted]").text()` does not contain a space.

Comment: <meta>Let's stay friendly to each other guys ;) Given the way commenting and editions work in this forum, it's obvious that 2+ people can write the same thing at the same time. No big deal.</meta>